# Alexander-Whitney for cyclic objects

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology

What is known about the extension of the AW map from simplicial to cyclic Abelian groups? Homological perturbation theory implies there is an A infinity-like sequence of maps, but is it known explicitly, or written down somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow!